# Test of being false does not work with unserialize

Tags: php

I want to decrypt a string when submitting form after entering an input string to be decrypted :

```
    static function decrypt($data) {
        $key = 'AVtr34EN';
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,"",MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,"");
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
        $data = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($data));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

        if (substr($data,0,1) != '!')
            return false;

        $data = substr($data,1,strlen($data)-1);
        return unserialize($data);
    }
```

When I call this function provided with an argument value of :

```
zeL1smxhfIEMWCews6vb1Y8yFa5tHbB3b489X0R3QtA=
```

then I get nothing !

I made a test `if ( utils::decrypt($data_) === false )` but the program does not enter in the block of the if !

So how to treat this case ?

Comment: code works for me, What about adding `{ }` brackets around the IF statement.

Comment: I already added brackets but still got nothing !

Comment: You realise your if check `$data` is not the same `$data` that you give the function?

Comment: the $data in the if is not same $data in the function : `$txt_crypter = $this->param("txt_crypter");  $txt_decrypter = utils::decrypt($txt_crypter);`  I use Jelix framework thats why you see the code $this->param

Comment: why do you name two different variables the same? that's silly.

Comment: the first is one I declare and the second is one from POST request.

Comment: that makes no sense, read your comments and then see how you get a function with two `$data` variables from a function with an input of one data variable. Please clarify where your variables come from, such as post requests and the code your postin your comments, these are all not stated in the question and don't seem to relate to the code that is stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give the string `zeL1smxhfIEMWCews6vb1Y8yFa5tHbB3b489X0R3QtA=` and using this andsandboxing the PHP it works exactly as expected:

```
static function decrypt($data) {
    $key = 'AVtr34EN';
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,"",MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,"");
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
    $data = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($data));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

    //$data = "!s:20:"2�Y:H���6|1|2|1|2|4";���"

    if (substr($data,0,1) != '!')
        return false;

    // If will never be reached in this case,
    // as data first character does equal "!" 

    $data = substr($data,1,strlen($data)-1);
    return unserialize($data); //"2�Y:H���6|1|2|1|2|4"
}
```

Please clarify your question. changing the inpt string to `"FDHFDHeh"` (or whatever) correctly returns `false` showing the IF statement is fired.

**NOTE:**

You are using an input `$data` variable but then also generating a new `$data` variable in the function, this is bad practise to have two different things with the same name, and judging by comments this is causing me, if not you, confusion.

Also you can simplify the `substr` as simply  `$data = substr($data,1);` as because you're starting at character 1, the string length with be `strlen($data)-1`.

---

Recommended you rewrite:

```
 static function decrypt($data) {
        $key = 'AVtr34EN';
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,"",MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,"");
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
        $decryptData = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($data));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

        if (substr($decryptData,0,1) !== '!'){
            //re: comments below:
            //using !== makes it a strict type comparison 
            return false;
            }

        $outputData = substr($decryptData,1);
        return unserialize($data);
    }
```

It *may* also be worthwhile using the `mb_string` functions.

You can also rewrite the string comparison using arrays (as a string is an array of letters) so, replace `if(substr(...))` with:

```
if ($decryptData[0] !== '!')
            return false;
```

Which means *"IF the first character of variable `$decryptData` is not "!"* then return false.

Comment: the input string I provided made my program bug ! if you replace it to `zeL1smxhfIEMWCews6vblY8yFa5tHbB3b489X0R3QtA=` then the function does not return false !

Comment: Why should that string return false, as exampled on my answer, that string -- when decrypted-- starts with a "!".  see no problems with the code.

Comment: how to write the test to be strict ?